# Making two column divs equal height

Tags: css, html, background

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="leftColumn">
    left column stuff
  </div>
  <div id="rightColumn">
    right column sidebar stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

When the left column is longer than the right, the right column's background image gets cut off. How do I make both columns the same height?  (I tried applying a background image to the content div and it fixed the problem, but some pages don't use the sidebar so I'm trying to look for another solution).

the columns also can't be fixed height.

Comment: `#leftColumn, #rightColumn{
         height: 500px;
    }`

Comment: the columns can't be fixed height.

Comment: this might not work for IE6/7 but you can set it `min-height: 500px`

Comment: In css set height for both divs

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care so much about IE6 and IE7, the simplest answer is setting

`display: table-cell;`

on each of your columns.
Just check http://ie7nomore.com/css2only/table-layout/ for this pure CSS2.1 solution (both columns are contenteditable so you can easily add lines and lines of text in one and/or another column)
And no it isn't "using tables" as some may argue : the `table` value of the CSS property `display` renders the same way as a the HTML element `table` but it's still the semantic of a `div` (i.e. none) or whatever element it's applied to ;)

Then for IE6 and IE7, you can use conditional comments for a simple fallback (like applying background to one of the column and if the other is longer in some pages ... nevermind and forget it, it's old IE and your text is still readable)

Answer (score 2):

If you want both columns to be the same height, yet their contents are different lengths, you need to set the height of the divs. You are asking for it to be fluid and expand to their length -- yet you want them to be the same which is just not possible.

kjy112 offered a good solution with min-height, but they are correct in saying that it indeed does not work in IE6 or 7.

You may want to take a look at this article:
http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

For another solution, you could try making the columns always expand to the column with the greatest height. Very good explanation of the problem here:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using jQuery, there is a plugin written specifically to address this issue.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/equal-height-columns

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a container div and define it as `display:table-row`, and the two children, define as `display:table-cell;height:100%;`. That's how I handled it here: heyvian.com/html5-css3 and if you add content in the `contenteditable` side you'll see how it works.

I doubt this works in ie6 or ie7 though. I haven't tested that page for those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

i just came across this and saw there's no green tag on either answer yet.. Maybe one of these methods could help ->

http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/four-methods-to-create-equal-height-columns/

(some of it is already mentioned here - but i still find it a nice overview with pros and cons and lots of comments)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very simple:

First you have to add a class named "elements" to both columns so your html will look like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="leftColumn" class="elements">
    left column stuff
  </div>
  <div id="rightColumn" class="elements">
    right column sidebar stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

After this, all you have to do is to compare the 2 heights, and aplay the maximum height to the smallest one. You do this like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var highestCol = Math.max($('#leftColumn').height(),$('#rightColumn').height());
    $('.elements').height(highestCol);      
});
```

Its a jQuery code witch calculate the maximum height between the 2 columns, and set them both with that height, resulting 2 columns with the same height. (the biggest one)

Answer (score 0):

Since some pages don't use a sidebar you can give and ID to your `<body>` tag and swap backgrounds that way.  As far as a solution that works in all browsers, you're out of luck.  I haven't found any.

```
#about-me { background: url(about.png) repeat-y; }
#contact { background: url(contact.png) repeat-y; }

<body id="about-me">
```

or

```
<body id="contact">
```