# side by side divs with same height

Tags: css, html, height

How can I put the height of side by side DIVs?

When I change the width of browser, sometimes the left div get higher or shorter than the left.

I want that automatically the left or the right div grows up to became with the same height of the other one.

Setting a display table-row is the best solution for this?

Take a look at the image of the page I want to develop.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7aty.png

---

I solved the problem using display=table-row, table and table-cell. I've added one div to be the table.
Now it is perfect! Take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/tcWCC/47/

Comment: Do you need it to be floating? Then please look existing question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873781/how-to-make-floating-inner-divs-the-same-height-as-the-highest-div . Otherwise, look for example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146665/making-two-column-divs-equal-height/5146935

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

Comment: It's different. It's like a table. But each row must have a space between them. And each cell also must have a space. Like in the picture http://i.imgur.com/BhvV2.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem using display=table-row, table and table-cell. I've added one div to be the table. Now it is perfect! Take a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/tcWCC/47/

Comment: This is a great solution, simple and no hacks. Just wanted to post this [link](http://demo.hongkiat.com/css-equal-height/) where it explains this in more detail and actually explains 2 alternative CSS methods (including faux column method suggested by @Grigor).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution, also found on SO

http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/

Here is the link to original post

[How do I keep two divs that are side by side the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997767/how-do-i-keep-two-divs-that-are-side-by-side-the-same-height)

The technique is called Faux Columns and here is an article about it

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: I can't use this because I have the radius-border. the bottom borders are curved.

Comment: If you have a sugestion I can. But the columns height should be equal even after resizing of window. I want to build a liquid layout that works in table, mobile phones and desktop. I want somethink like a table row. but each row can't be collapsed in the above or bellow row.

Comment: Well, than you can use the plugin called `.equalHeights();` Here is the link to the plugin: http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying yo do is to place the content in a grey box with rounded conrners then your divs don't need to be of the same height. Just move the background-color and border-radius to the enclosing div: http://jsfiddle.net/tcWCC/41/

Comment: Setting a display table-row is the best solution for this?

Comment: I cant't do this because there is a separation between divs.

Answer (score -4):

I think you won't be able to do that without using a html table.

Comment: This type of functionality is certainly not limited to tables!

Comment: It's also important to have a margin between each line.