# Make a div expandable without specifying any height to it

Tags: html, css

This is my Html,

```
<div id="wrapper" class='common'>
    <div id="left" class='common'>Menu I Menu II Menu III Menu IV</div>
    <div id="right" class='common'>hello world..hello world..hello world..
      hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..
      hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..
      hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..
      hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..hello world..
      hello world..hello world..
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS,

```
#wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:3px;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width:70%;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:29%;
}
.common {
    border:solid 1px #000;
}
```

And here you can see the [**`demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/NSee7/) of it.

I am just trying to make the div with id left to be expandable based on the content of the div which is having the id right. i just tried to make that on my own but i failed. can anybody help me out by expelling some clues..?

Comment: @AmitJoki `div with id left to be expandable based on the content of the div which is having the id right.`

Comment: Try this. Remove floats and add `display:table-cell` to `#right` and `#left`

Comment: @James It just collapsed everything.. http://jsfiddle.net/NSee7/1/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I'm asking whether you want "expand by dragging" as we have in fiddle.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you missed ";" after the css declaration. `display:table-cell;`

Comment: @AmitJoki check his fiddle in the comment. He didn't add the ";" after the `display:table-cell` style. He said it was collapsing.

Comment: @James, I deleted my comment. Sorry. You were right

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy check Ben D's answer because the structure should be as he said `table > table-row > table-cell`. Sorry i missed that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriate pure-css mechanism for doing this is through using `display:table*` to declare `#left` and `#right` as sibling columns. This will cause them to display as the same height when they are cast as `display:table-cell`. The only caveat is that you'll need one more wrapper `div` because a you need a structure that looks like  `display:table` > `display:table-row` > `display: table-cell`.

I've added a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QDh59/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use html css only, check this link:

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

If you have no prob using javascript/jquery it would be much easier and more straightforward:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/equal-height-columns-with-javascript-full-version/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using the `height:` attribute, with absolute positioning.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9hv6M/)

Answer (score 0):

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517829/side-by-side-divs-with-same-height)

I don't think it's easy to make 2 divs expand alone without wrapper like the answers you see in the links.

There are techniques like [Faux Columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) that can help you get what you asked for too and there are many other techniques.

Using CSS:

[Faux Columns and CSS Table](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-equal-height/)

Using Jquery:

[Equalize Heights of Divs](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/equalize-heights-of-divs/)